# Why does GoogleCloudMessaging.register always return a different token while the documentation reads otherwise?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

The [documentation for `GoogleCloudMessaging.register`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html#register%28java.lang.String...%29) says:

> Register the application for GCM and return the registration ID. You
>   must call this once, when your application is installed, and send the
>   returned registration ID to the server.
>
> Repeated calls to this method will return the original registration
>   ID.

Why is that when I call this method, repeatedly, I always get a different device registration key. I might have missed some thing but shouldn't I be getting the same registration token, always?

Comment: id is not going to be same. When you re-request for register id may change.

Comment: You might be calling at some point in your code, `unregister()` http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html#unregister()

Comment: It is the same while the app stays installed. ID is simply stored in shared preferences and if you uninstall the app, delete the app data or unregister you get a new id.

Comment: @zapl `It is the same while the app stays installed` what does it mean...? And what about Google refreshes registration id after some time.. is that changed in new API?

Comment: Oops, forget what I said, I was referring to old GCM.

Comment: @SunilMishra, I checked my code and there aren't any calls to the `unregister` method. Although I agree that `register` method should only be invoked once, shouldn't the method's functionality be compliant with the documentation? Thanks.